# data-type="" ... needed post tags stripped of characters

Tags: custom-post-types, sanitization, tags

So I am trying to generate a list of post tags on the data-type attribute but I need them to be sanitized so spaces are replaced with underscores and there are no special characters... really struggling with it.

```
                <article class="work_items">

                <?php
                  query_posts(array( 'post_type' => 'work', 'posts_per_page' => '-1', 'orderby'=>'title','order'=>'ASC'));
                  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                ?>

                    <aside class="work_item" data-id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" data-type="
<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tag = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '_');
        echo $tag->name . ' ';
      }
    }
?>">

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <div class="img_wrap">
                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'Work Gallery', array('class' => 'lazy', 299,299)); ?>
                                </div><!-- /.img_wrap-->
                                <ul class="work_meta">
                                    <li class="work_title"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
                                    <li class="work_item_content"><?php echo excerpt(25); ?></li>
                                    <?php
                                        if( has_tag() ) {
                                            // IF THE POST HAS TAGS
                                            the_tags('<li class="work_tags first">', '.</li><li class="work_tags">', '.</li>');
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            // IF NO TAGS
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </ul>
                                <ul class="work_features">
                                    <li class="view_all"><a class="tooltip" title="full details" href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">View All</a></li>
                                    <li class="expand"><a rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]" class="expanded tooltip" title="preview" href="#prettyPhoto-<?php the_id(); ?>">Expand</a></li>
                                    <li class="lightbox">
                                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); ?>
                                            <a class="work_lb tooltip" title="view in lightbox" href="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" rel="prettyPhoto">Lightbox</a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </aside><!-- /.work_item-->
```

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tag->slug` instead of `tag->name`.

Spaces and special characters will be replaced by dashes but altering that is easy:

```
echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug);
```

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: That worked like a charm only issue is its replacing special characters with "-" and I need them to be replaced with "_" ... any ideas on that one?